# Total results of paged projected nhibernate query with aggregates

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I'm dynamically building a nhibernate projected query that needs to implement paging. Something like...

```
var projections = Projections.ProjectionList();
foreach (var p in projection.Projections)
{
    IProjection newProjection = null;
    switch (p.AggregateFunc)
    {
        case AggregateFuncTypeEnum.GroupProperty:
            newProjection = Projections.GroupProperty(p.Path);
            break;
        case AggregateFuncTypeEnum.Sum:
            newProjection = Projections.Sum(p.Path);
            break;
        default:
            newProjection = Projections.Property(p.Path);
            break;
    }
    projections.Add(newProjection, p.Name);
}
criteria.SetProjection(projections).SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(projectionType));
```

I can get the first 15 results like so

```
criteria.SetFirstResult(0);
criteria.SetMaxResults(15);
var results = criteria.List();
```

But I also need to send another query to get the total number of records but so far I've failed to figure this out. The projection still needs to be applied i.e. if the results are grouped by 'code' with a sum of 'cost' then 100 records might return 20 rows, and it's the 20 I'm interested in.

How do I get the total number of records that will be returned? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this:

```
var rowcount = CriteriaTransformer.Clone(criteria);

var goupprojections = Projections.ProjectionList();
var projections = Projections.ProjectionList();
foreach (var p in projection.Projections)
{
    IProjection newProjection = null;
    switch (p.AggregateFunc)
    {
        case AggregateFuncTypeEnum.GroupProperty:
            newProjection = Projections.GroupProperty(p.Path);
            goupprojections.Add(Projections.GroupProperty(p.Path), p.Name);
            break;
        case AggregateFuncTypeEnum.Sum:
            newProjection = Projections.Sum(p.Path);
            break;
        default:
            newProjection = Projections.Property(p.Path);
            break;
    }
    projections.Add(newProjection, p.Name);
}
criteria.SetProjection(projections).SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(projectionType));

if (goupprojections.Aliases.Length == 0)
{
    rowcount.SetProjection(Projections.RowCount())
}
else
{
    rowcount.SetProjection(Projections.Count(goupprojections))
}

var results = criteria.Future();
var count = rowcount.FutureValue<int>();
```

Comment: This still seems to return a count of e.g. 100 instead of the 20 rows that are returned by the projection (e.g. grouped by 'Code' and with a sum of 'Cost')

Comment: `rowcount.SetProjection(Projections.Count(goupprojections))` should do imo, i'll check

Comment: Looks like it should but not for me at least. Using your idea I can pick a single property to group by using CountDistinct but this only accepts a single property

Comment: i can confirm that, if i `Projections.Count(Projections.Distinct(projlist))` then NH is inserting an as in the distinct and doing sql it seems SQLlite doesnt support more than 1 property in Distinct so i cant test further here

Comment: 'rowcount.SetProjection(Projections.Count(goupprojections))' does produce Count put leaves out the groupings. "SELECT Count(prop) FROM table GROUP BY prop" returns Count of each group in Postgresql and SQLite.

Comment: `var subquery = DetachedCriteria.For<User>()
                    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("FirstName"))
                    );`
and `session.CreateCriteria<Something>().SetProjection(Projections.Count(Projections.SubQuery(subquery)))` does produce proper SQL but database returns ungrouped count in sqlite and error in POstGres

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've currently had to settle for a "poor man's count" against one grouped column because as you've commented what seems like it should work doesn't.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue? I'm struggling to get the same query as you have in your question above to work!
Please help me out if you have a solution. Thanks

Comment: @adam Please let me know of the solution you came up with.