# How to count all posts belonging to multiple tags in NHibernate?

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I have a many to many relationship:

- A post can have many tags
- A tag can have many posts

Models:

```
public class Post
{
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Content{ get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

I want to count all posts that belong to multiple tags but I don't know how to do this in NHibernate. I am not sure if this is the best way to do this but I used this query in MS SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT Posts.Id FROM Posts
    INNER JOIN Users ON Posts.UserId=Users.Id 
    LEFT JOIN TagsPosts ON Posts.Id=TagsPosts.PostId 
    LEFT JOIN Tags ON TagsPosts.TagId=Tags.Id 
    WHERE Users.Username='mr.nuub' AND (Tags.Title in ('c#', 'asp.net-mvc')) 
    GROUP BY Posts.Id 
    HAVING COUNT(Posts.Id)=2
    )t
```

But NHibernate does not allow subqueries in the from clause. It would be great if someone could show me how to do this in HQL.

Comment: Why don't you just get rid of the subquery since you aren't doing anything with it? Just `COUNT(Posts.Id)`??

Comment: That returns 3 rows: '2', '2', '2'. I am now counting the results of the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way of how to get this result without a sub query and this works with nHibernate Linq. It was actually not that easy because of the subset of linq expressions which are supported by nHibernate... but anyways

query:

```
var searchTags = new[] { "C#", "C++" };
var result = session.Query<Post>()
        .Select(p => new { 
            Id = p.Id, 
            Count = p.Tags.Where(t => searchTags.Contains(t.Title)).Count() 
        })
        .Where(s => s.Count >= 2)
        .Count();
```

It produces the following sql statment:

```
select cast(count(*) as INT) as col_0_0_ 
from Posts post0_ 
where (
    select cast(count(*) as INT)
    from PostsToTags tags1_, Tags tag2_ 
    where post0_.Id=tags1_.Post_id 
    and tags1_.Tag_id=tag2_.Id 
    and (tag2_.Title='C#' or tag2_.Title='C++'))>=2
```

you should be able to build your user restriction into this, I hope.

The following is my test setup and random data which got generated

```
public class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
        Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }
    public virtual void AddTag(Tag tag)
    {
        this.Tags.Add(tag);
        tag.Posts.Add(this);
    }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class PostMap : ClassMap<Post>
{
    public PostMap()
    {
        Table("Posts");

        Id(p => p.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();

        Map(p => p.Content);

        Map(p => p.Title);

        HasManyToMany<Tag>(map => map.Tags).Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class Tag
{
    public Tag()
    {
        Posts = new List<Post>();
    }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class TagMap : ClassMap<Tag>
{
    public TagMap()
    {
        Table("Tags");
        Id(p => p.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();

        Map(p => p.Description);
        Map(p => p.Title);
        HasManyToMany<Post>(map => map.Posts).LazyLoad().Inverse();
    }
}
```

test run:

```
var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012
        .ConnectionString(@"Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;")
        .ShowSql)
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
        .AddFromAssemblyOf<PostMap>())
    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true))
    .BuildSessionFactory();

using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    var t1 = new Tag() { Title = "C#", Description = "C#" };
    session.Save(t1);
    var t2 = new Tag() { Title = "C++", Description = "C/C++" };
    session.Save(t2);
    var t3 = new Tag() { Title = ".Net", Description = "Net" };
    session.Save(t3);
    var t4 = new Tag() { Title = "Java", Description = "Java" };
    session.Save(t4);
    var t5 = new Tag() { Title = "lol", Description = "lol" };
    session.Save(t5);
    var t6 = new Tag() { Title = "rofl", Description = "rofl" };
    session.Save(t6);
    var tags = session.Query<Tag>().ToList();
    var r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        var post = new Post()
        {
            Title = "Title" + i,
            Content = "Something awesome" + i,
        };

        var manyTags = r.Next(1, 3);

        while (post.Tags.Count() < manyTags)
        {
            var index = r.Next(0, 6);
            if (!post.Tags.Contains(tags[index]))
            {
                post.AddTag(tags[index]);
            }
        }

        session.Save(post);
    }
    session.Flush();

    /* query test */
    var searchTags = new[] { "C#", "C++" };
    var result = session.Query<Post>()
            .Select(p => new { 
                Id = p.Id, 
                Count = p.Tags.Where(t => searchTags.Contains(t.Title)).Count() 
            })
            .Where(s => s.Count >= 2)
            .Count();

    var resultOriginal = session.CreateQuery(@"
       SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM 
        (
        SELECT count(Posts.Id)P FROM Posts
        LEFT JOIN PostsToTags ON Posts.Id=PostsToTags.Post_id 
        LEFT JOIN Tags ON PostsToTags.Tag_id=Tags.Id 
        WHERE Tags.Title in ('c#', 'C++')
        GROUP BY Posts.Id 
        HAVING COUNT(Posts.Id)>=2
        )t
    ").List()[0];

    var isEqual = result == (int)resultOriginal;
}
```

As you can see at the end I do test against your original query (without the users) and it is actually the same count.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works great :) Could you also give an example in HQL?

Comment: It is actually a good idea to not use HQL, because strongly typed > all... And no your posted hql doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

Edit : In the future I should read the questions until the last words. I would have seen `in HQL`...

---

After some seach, realizing that `RowCount` removes any grouping in the query ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/8034921/1236044 ). I found a solution using `QueryOver` and `SubQuery` which I post here as information. 
I find this solution interesting as it offers some modularity, and seprates the counting from the subquery itself, which can be reused as it is.

```
var searchTags = new[] { "tag1", "tag3" };
var userNames = new[] { "mr.nuub" };
Tag tagAlias = null;
Post postAlias = null;
User userAlias = null;

var postsSubquery =
    QueryOver.Of<Post>(() => postAlias)
            .JoinAlias(() => postAlias.Tags, () => tagAlias)
            .JoinAlias(() => postAlias.User, () => userAlias)
            .WhereRestrictionOn(() => tagAlias.Title).IsIn(searchTags)
            .AndRestrictionOn(() => userAlias.UserName).IsIn(userNames)
            .Where(Restrictions.Gt(Projections.Count<Post>(p => tagAlias.Title), 1));

var numberOfPosts = session.QueryOver<Post>()
            .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(p => p.Id).In(postsSubquery.Select(Projections.Group<Post>(p => p.Id)))
            .RowCount();
```

Hope this will help

Comment: @Mr.nuub does it produce a query or does it crash before that ? Edited my answer by adding a final projection

Comment: It crashes on this line: .AndRestrictionOn(p=>p.User.UserName).IsIn(userNames) but I only have one user so I can leave it for now. The result of this query is 5 for tags 'c#' and 'asp.net-mvc'. But it should be 2.

Comment: @Mr.nuub thx for the follow-up. Edited my answer, the question happened to be more complex than it first seemed. For information, edited my answer. For the sake of maintainability, you should avoid HQL, and prefer Query or QueryOver API.

Answer (score 0):

In HQL:

```
var hql = "select count(p) from Post p where p in " +
    "(select t.Post from Tag t group by t.Post having count(t.Post) > 1)";
var result = session.Query(hql).UniqueResult<long>();
```

You can add additional criteria to the subquery if you need to specify tags or other criteria.